# jQuery Validate: Validating multiple forms on single page if has same value

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate, multiple-forms

Example if I have multiple forms, how I can validate the "identity_passport" must be different cannot be the same:

```
<form id="form_1">
  <input name="name_1">
  <input name="email_1">
  <input name="identity_passport_1" data-field="identity_passport">
</form>

<form id="form_2">
  <input name="name_2">
  <input name="email_2">
  <input name="identity_passport_2" data-field="identity_passport">
</form>

<form id="form_3">
  <input name="name_3">
  <input name="email_3">
  <input name="identity_passport_3" data-field="identity_passport">
</form>

<button type="submit" id="button_submit">Submit</button>
```

I have custom submit button that place outside of the form in a single page. I am using .each() method like (below):

```
<script>
  $('form').each(function () {

    $(this).validate({
      errorElement: "span",
      errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
        //
      },
      success: function (label, element) {
        //
      },
      highlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
        //
      }
    });

  });
</script>
```

**UPDATE 2018/01/25:**
After a long try, is possible. Here is my test and demo:
https://jsfiddle.net/claudchan/4t41kjLr/4/

Comment: Why don't you use only one form?

Comment: Each form is dynamically added.

Comment: That doesn't answer my question. Why don't you use _one_ form and only add the new "identities"

Comment: I think I get your point but i do not know how does the 'groups' work. If you could provide an example?

Comment: This is not a duplicate.  The OP wants to validate fields across multiple different forms.  Unfortunately, this is not possible using jQuery Validate.

Comment: As stated previously, use a single form and dynamically add new fields.  There are already tons of examples of this on SO.

Answer (score 1):

> *Example if I have multiple forms, how I can validate the "identity_passport" must be different...*

It is not possible using jQuery Validate to simultaneously validate fields across different `form` containers.

The jQuery Validate plugin evaluates a *single form at a time* using its rules and settings. It cannot evaluate any fields contained within another completely separate form.  Nor can it evaluate fields from different forms against each other.

---

Workaround: use a single `form` container and [dynamically add your fields](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjquery-validate%5D%20dynamically%20add%20fields).  As long as you maintain unique `name` attributes, it will work.

Answer (score 1):

There is a jquery plugin is available to validate the form
and you can also validate your form without it. you just have to keep in mind is that **each** keyword will trigger only one form. 
Don't use **ID** if you have multiple forms with for same task it will give you an HTML DOM error. Instead of that use the class name to validate.

```
$('form').each(function() {   // <- selects every <form> on page
    $(this).validate({        // <- initialize validate() on each form
        // your options       // <- set your options inside
    });
});
```